# How to write firebase cloud functions in java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new in firebase . I am store data in firebase database using admin sdk(java code ). I have done this part successfully . Now i want write fire base cloud function on create of database entry and notification as

```
1. The function triggers on writes to the Realtime Database path where followers are stored.
2. The function composes a message to send via FCM.
3. FCM sends the notification message to the user's device.
```

As i have search more on internet , found only node.js code for that.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Is it possible to  write firebase cloud function 
using admin sdk or java code.Please help me.

Comment: I think Firebase cloud functions only allow for JavaScript. They are running on a node.js server so I don't think you can use Java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT: May 30, 2020**

There is now support for Java/JVM in Cloud Functions.  Please see the [release blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-java-11-on-google-cloud-functions) and [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/jvm-langs) for information.

**Original answer**

For Cloud Functions, there is currently no support for Java or any other languages or environments other than JavaScript in a node.js environment.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation

Comment: But you can call cloud functions from java library right?
See this: [Google cloud functions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/cloudfunctions/v1)

Comment: But Firebase cloud functions are somehow Google Cloud Functions at heart--and I assume that latter support many different languages. Is the issue the ability to tie them to HTTP/Database/Storage triggers?

Comment: GCP Cloud Functions now has a Java runtime currently in Alpha. See my response for more details.

Comment: When can we expect the new java 11 support in GCP to be officially supported in Firebase Functions?

Answer (score 9):

GCP Cloud Functions now has a Java Runtime.

At this time it is currently in alpha, but I would expect it to release to Beta rather quickly.

- [Java Runtime Alpha Sign-up](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScC98jGi7CfG0n3UYlj7Xad8XScvZC8-BBOg7Pk3uSZx_2cdQ/viewform) (available on [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/your-favorite-runtimes-now-generally-available-on-cloud-functions)
- [Google Next 19 announcement video](https://youtu.be/WnhAYX1Phxw?t=390)

Comment: This is exciting/promising news. Let's see if there is a big Google I/O announcement. This Medium [Setting up Firebase Functions with Kotlin](https://medium.com/@LuhmirinS/setting-up-firebase-functions-with-kotlin-1c34b2ca2427) seems to be a good workaround in the meantime. I have not implemented/tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Java currently for cloud functions in Firebase. You can use JavaScript or TypeScript for this.

[Firebase Cloud Functions using TypeScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript)

Comment: you can now since May 30, 2020

Comment: Thats great news indeed. Thanks for sharing.