# How to run a JAVA program in response to Cloud storage trigger in Firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an android app with Firebase server. What I really need is to run JAVA face recognition algorithm in the server whenever the cloud storage received an image.

I searched a lot but not found any helpful material. I just want to know the steps to make the whole setup for aforementioned problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions can currently only run JavaScript. It cannot run Java code. Also see: [How to write firebase cloud functions in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573981/how-to-write-firebase-cloud-functions-in-java)

If the face recognition software is only available in Java, you may want to consider hosting it elsewhere (your own server, or a Java hosting platform) and then call out to it from your Cloud Functions.

Comment: Can we call out other platforms like google cloud through these cloud functions in firebase?? thank you

Comment: Since these are (for the most part) just Node.js script, yes that is definitely possible. But note that to call out to external servers, your project needs to be on a paid plan.

Comment: can i interlink Firebase with a Java program in Google cloud??

Comment: You could run a separate Java service in App Engine, and trigger it by sending it a pub/sub message to that service from the Cloud Function.